# Laravel Filemanager Base url for Images is wrong

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, unisharp-file-manager

I need help configuring the site url being generated by Laravel File manager. I am developing my application locally on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. The name of the application is security. But whenever I upload images, its giving them a url of: http://security.test/storage/photos/1/logo-small.jpeg

How can I change this incorrect url to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/1/logo-small.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change in `.env` file:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

After making change in `.env` file remember to execute the following command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thats it good friend, all problems gone, thank you.